# Read CSV into Two Dimensional Array using First Line as Keys

Tags: php, arrays, csv, dimensional

I'm trying to Read a CSV file, where the format is:

```
titleA,titleB,titleC

data1A,data1B,data1C

data2A,data2B,data3C
```

The OUTPUT expected is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[titleA] => data1A
[titleB] => data1B
[titleC] => data1C
)

[1] => Array
(
[titleA] => data2A
[titleB] => data2B
[titleC] => data2C
)
```

I tried using something that I foound here:

```
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$twoDarray[] = $data;
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

But it shows 1 array with all the titles and other 2 Arrays with Data.

Answer (score 2):

You want to read the first line and use it as the keys and combine:

```
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {    
    $titles = fgetcsv($handle, 1000);

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        $twoDarray[] = array_combine($titles, $data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take firslt as heading and then combine it with each row.

```
$heading = array();
$heading_check =1;
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($heading_check){
            $heading = $data;
            $heading_check=0;
            continue;
        }

        $twoDarray[] = array_combine($heading,$data);
    }
fclose($handle);
}
```